# How to build a synchronization mechanism between local and remote database in Android application?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I added features that users can use our service (POS) in an offline mode. But when the user goes online all the data he inserts (sold products) are synced with the server database. What is the new and best mechanism for android?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you want to dump all unconfirmed objects to the server after going online?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very open question.

Have you looked at https://github.com/dropbox/Store

> A Store is a class that simplifies fetching, sharing, storage, and retrieval of data in your application. A Store is similar to the Repository pattern while exposing an API built with Coroutines that adheres to a unidirectional data flow.

Answer (score -1):

```
synchronized(this) {
    val roomdatabaseinstance =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context, Notesdatabase::class.java, "Notes")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries().build()
    INSTANCE = roomdatabaseinstance
    return roomdatabaseinstance
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).